# get result in dynamo db based on list of elements

Tags: python, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to dynamo db and want to compare values of a list(python) with attribute value of dynamo db table.
I am able to compare single value by using query with index key:

```
response = dynamotable.query(
    IndexName='Classicmovies',
    KeyConditionExpression = Key('DDT').eq('BBB-rrr-jjj-mq'))
```

but want to compare entire list which should be in .eq as follow:

```
movies =['ddd-dddss-gdgdg','kkdf-dfdfd-www','dfw-gddf-gssg']
```

I have searched alot and not able to figure out right way.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what you are trying to do. A query will only retrieve a bunch of records belonging to a single item collection. Maybe what you need is a scan but please avoid heavily using scans unless of its for maintenance purposes.